# How to convert the struct array type returned by Solidity function to Go type?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

solidity version 0.6.10

```
struct LogisticsData {
        address cargo;
        address orgin;
        address destination;
        string memo;
        uint createdAt;
        uint queryCount;
}

function getLogisticsInfo(address cargo) public returns(LogisticsData[] memory _cargoLogisticsData) {
    _cargoLogisticsData = new LogisticsData[](3);
   // do something
}
```

Go code generated by abigen

```
type LogisticsLogisticsData struct {
    Cargo       common.Address
    Orgin       common.Address
    Destination common.Address
    Memo        string
    CreatedAt   *big.Int
    QueryCount  *big.Int
}
```

I tried the following code, but it returned an error.

```
_, receipt, _ := instance.GetLogisticsInfo(client.GetTransactOpts(), common.HexToAddress(address))
parsedAbi, _ := abi.JSON(strings.NewReader(logistics.LogisticsABI))
temp := make([]logistics.LogisticsLogisticsData, 10)
err = parsedAbi.Unpack(&temp, "getLogisticsInfo", []byte(receipt.Output))
fmt.Println(err) // abi: improperly formatted output: xxx
```

I want to convert the return data to a LogisticsLogisticsData struct. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Need to convert from hexadecimal to binary

```
bytesOutput, _ := hex.DecodeString(receipt.Output[2:])
err = parsedAbi.Unpack(&temp, "getLogisticsInfo", bytesOutput)
```